# Grails: Displaying the code not the message: Idea on how to debug

Tags: grails, internationalization

This is a weird issue and I could not find anyone post the same problem as this.

I've been working on one module of my project, I'm already finishing up when I noticed that grails is not displaying the message but the code in i18n messages. The most weird part is, all other modules display the label / messages properly except for this new module that I'm working on. It was working before, I don't know what happened, or waht I did.

I know it's hard for you to give solution for this, but could you give an idea where should I be looking at, or what debugging technique can I do so that I can fix this?

There's no error message in the IDE that's why I could not give you any more info. Please note that I've already restarted many times my IDE, and my computer. I've also deleted the cache. And when I set the default value, like this..

```
<div class="fieldcontain required">

    <div class="input_div">
        <div class="customCheckBoxDiv">

            <g:checkBox class="checkBoxInput" name="checkBoxName" checked="true" value="true"/>
            <label for="checkBoxName"></label>

        </div>

        <label for="instanceFieldName" class="form_label checkbox_text">
            <g:message code="dialog.checkbox.label" default="Default value" encodeAs="HTML"/>
        </label>
    </div>
</div>
```

Grails would display the "Default value". So it seems like, It could not really find the declaration of that label in i18n.

Comment: Do you mean by `I've also deleted the cache`, executing `grails clean`? Did you also try to manually delete */bin* and  */build* folders and after that run-app?

Comment: @Michal_Szulc no, just the browser's cache. But executing "grails clean" fixed it.Thanks :)